# Using SC command for devices in the backend

Tags: windows, server, command, windows-server-2008-r2

can somebody help me with a query I have. I have a device (windows server 2008) at the backend that when it fail we need to restart a service a service in the server.

I have read that I can send a the command to the device remotly with ( sc \server stop service)

The only concern is that the device is a the backend and a some firewall rules that don't let us remote control.

SC use any port to send the command that maybe I can open in the firewall?

Comment: I think it's called "remote services administration" or similar.  The folks over at Server Fault (serverfault.com) will be able to tell you.

Comment: thanks I  wil try them.